# wp7 strange UnhandledException on databinding 0x8000ffff

Tags: data-binding, windows-phone-7

I am getting a strange unhandled exception during databinding. I am databinding a ListBox with an IList. After populating the list with the objects, I set the DataContext of the ListBox to my object:

```
IList<Users> users = new List<Users>;
foreach(JToken jresult in Users)
{
User juser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(jresult.ToString());
users.Add(juser);

this.DataContext = myObject;
```

My object has just two fields, name and email:

```
public class User
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }    }
```

On the XAML side, I am binding the ListItem and the text blocks within the ItemTemplate as follows:

```
<ListBox Name="Users" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Name="name" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Email}" Name="email" />
```

During debugging I can see the Users listbox is getting populated with correct items, however after exiting out of the method, the application crashes, and I am taken directly to the App.xaml.cs method Application_UnhandledException. The error details are:

```
e.ExceptionObject.InnerException
{"0x8000ffff"}
    _data: null
    _HResult: -2146233088
    _innerException: null
    _message: "0x8000ffff"
    _methodDescs: {System.IntPtr[14]}
    _optionalData: null
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2146233088
    InnerException: Could not evaluate expression
    Message: "0x8000ffff"
    StackTrace: "   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)\r\n   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.FrameworkElement_MeasureOverride(FrameworkElement element, Size availableSize)\r\n   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)\r\n   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)\r\n   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MeasureNative(IntPtr element, Single inWidth, Single inHeight)\r\n   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_Measure(UIElement element, Size availableSize)\r\n   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)\r\n   at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureChild(UIElement child, Size layoutSlotSize)\r\n   at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)\r\n   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)\r\n   at MS.Internal.XcpImpor
ts.MeasureOverrideNative(IntPtr element, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)\r\n   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.FrameworkElement_MeasureOverride(FrameworkElement element, Size availableSize)\r\n   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)\r\n   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)\r\n"
```

I have not been able to figure this out, and would really appreciate any guidance, or maybe a better approach for this kind of problem. One article did mention that the ListDictionaryInternal is no longer supported in SilverLight, so I am not sure if that could be the issue, as the error details point to the ListDictionaryInternal.

Comment: Any new information about the cause of this error? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Want to hear something strange. I had this issue, and removed a style="{StaticResource ....} in the XAML and it fixed it. Can someone explain why? I added a local StaticResource right after that and it worked too.

If you have no Styles set anywhere in your ListBox item, then this solution will not help.

Comment: I found the error, it was in the xaml. I put a plain vanilla xaml and it worked fine. I then started to see the differences, and narrowed it down to a wrongly spelled color name for foreground color. I had somehow written "bl" instead of "black". Once I changed it to black, everything worked great! firebellys, thanks for the direction, it made me look at the item template and fixed it :)

Comment: Thank you SOOOO much! I would have never spotted that anyway :D

Comment: Seems this is what happens when the framework goes haywire in response to random mundane xaml errors.

After lots headdesk, I discovered that I had two menuitems with the same name. Goodbye 3 hours of my life, I will never see you again.

Comment: Thanks! Removing the style="{StaticResource ....}" from a TextBlock defined as a DataTemplate inside the ListBox.ItemTemplate solved the problem. But what the problem was?

Answer (score 0):

it's not about databinding I think it's general error When I was working about my Project my computer give me blue screen error and When I started my computer again I want to run my Project and I see 0x8000FFFF error I cant find exact solution on the net but I tried to DELETE licenses.licx file from visual studio I solved the problem :)